# Как получить последний пост из закрытой группы в вк?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Допустим, есть закрытое сообщество, я в нем не администратор, но я участник сообщества, я могу каким то образов в один запрос получитья последнюю пост из сообщества? Покурил метод wall.get не что то не получается.

Comment: Именно `wall.get` и надо докурить нормально, стоит писать ответ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    $wallInfo = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id={$group}&access_token={$token}&count=2&v=5.8"));
    foreach ($wallInfo->response->items as $item) {//перебираем полученные данные
        if(empty($item->is_pinned)) {//Проверяем закреплен ли пост, если нет
            echo $item->text;//То выводим текст поста
        }
    }
```

Работает с закрытой группой, главное состоять в ней

Comment: Если есть закреп, то такой код не сработает как надо. Нужно запрашивать два поста, а уж потом смотреть если у первого is_pinned=1, то нужный нам пост - 2й

Comment: @Александр Спасибо, исправил ответ